# Adding a 'Folder Group' using Outlook API

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to add a Folder Group to outlook using the Office API.  I can successfully add folders but I cannot figure out how to add a higher level folder

[image]

I would like to add my folder on the level of My Contacts or iCloud but I cant figure out how.  Im not even sure how to do it in outlook other than right-clicking My Contacts and making a new Folder Group then I have to create the folder under an exisitng group and then move it to my new group

Any ideas on how to acheive this programmatically

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook API class for "Folder Groups" is NavigationGroup.
Which could be gotten from Explorer class. 
The code below creates NavigationGroup with name "New Folder Group" and then adds outlook folder "New Folder" in this group. Code is very simple and doesn't check if any group or folder already exists or any other errors. Just sample to describe how API works.

```
string navigationGroupName = "New Folder Group";
string folderName = "New Folder";

ContactsModule contactsModule = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleContacts) as ContactsModule;

NavigationGroup navigationGroup = contactsModule.NavigationGroups.Create(navigationGroupName);

Folder contactFolder = (Folder) Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Folders.Add(folderName, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

navigationGroup.NavigationFolders.Add(contactFolder);
```